# Passing variable from AS3 to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I am currently doing a flash game that records the time taken and sending it to a php. Currently, my game is working and the time taken could be traced correctly. URLLoader is also working correctly however, my php page does not seem to be able to get the result from $_POST. I have posted my code below.

I would appreciate any help given. Have already tried various of methods but just could not work. I either get the processScore.php opening on a separate window and showing empty page or nothing happen at all. Thanks in advanced!

**AS3:**

```
function sendTime() {
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("processScore.php");
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        //using URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES give me error so I changed to TEXT.
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        var toSend:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        req.data = toSend;
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        toSend.timeRecorded = timeTaken;

        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, timeSent);
        loader.load(req);

    }

    function timeSent(e:Event) {
        trace("SENT");
    }
```

**processScore.php:**

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['timeRecorded'])) {
    echo $_POST['timeRecorded'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Use $_REQUEST instead.

Comment: I can't see the changes even if I changed to $_REQUEST. The page just remained on my flash page.

Comment: ok, now I have processScore.php popping out and said undefined index for timeRecorded.

Comment: Could you try running this through something like Fiddler?  That will tell you exactly what request your Flash game is sending.  Other than that, your code looks correct -- the only thing I'm not sure about is the `loader.dataFormat` line.

Comment: TEXT is the default so that line is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: You say: "The page just remained on my flash page" which could mean you don't know what you are doing here. URLLoader do not change page or navigate anywhere, there would be no reason for your flash page to go anywhere when using URLLoader.

Comment: what was the error with `URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES`? also add an error handler and see if it triggers

Comment: Well, I dont see what you are trying to achieve, do you want to open a separate page or you just want to send data to php while remain sitting on the flash page. In case you are trying to check if your php is getting correct timeRecorded from flash, trace this in your timeSent method trace(e.currentTarget.data); This will trace the response you echo in php, you can echo anything there and the same will popped up in flash output window,

Comment: @cleewt Your code looks fine, so the question is : how did you do your test ? To see a result, you can for example write that data in a text file : `$f = fopen('time.txt', 'w'); fwrite($f, $_POST['timeRecorded']); fclose($f);`, you can also do as it was mentioned by @sameer-jain using the `Event.COMPLETE` handler to show the `e.target.data` in a TextField for example ... of course if you are testing in Flash IDE (for example) don't forget to use an absolute URL of your PHP script : `http://localhost/processScore.php` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem. I did not really figure out the main idea behind URLLoader and hence I thought there was a problem when the flash page remains. The main issue was the absolute Url issue and i did not do anything to handle the result properly in php. Thanks everyone for throwing in the issues. I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function sendTime() {

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("processScore.php");
        var toSend:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        toSend.timeRecorded = timeTaken;
        req.data = toSend;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, timeSent);
        loader.load(req);

    }

    function timeSent(e:Event) {
        trace("SENT");
    }
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
        $timeRecorded = $_POST['timeRecorded'];
         echo $timeRecorded;
    ?>
```